# Auto Number Column in SharePoint List with Link to Item

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, custom-lists

There was a similar question posted regarding the same topic, but I'm adding to the question and the previous discussion was resolved.

Here is the link to the original question:  [Auto number column in SharePoint list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72537/auto-number-column-in-sharepoint-list/606872#606872)

I'm now trying to find out if in a Custom List in MOSS SharePoint 2007 there is a column called "ID(link to item)".
I know that when creating an Issues List in SharePoint, there exists an "Issue ID (link to item)" field that is by by default included in the view, however, I cannot find out if a similar field exists for a Custom List.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is No... but you can create one.

Cracking open a website using [SharePoint Manager](http://www.codeplex.com/spm) (which rocks) you can see the definition of the "IssueID" column and the one that is used to display the "ID(link to item)"
I include the schema xml from my site below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Field ID="{de57307b-e69a-4cf9-b3a9-b6a728ecf773}" Sealed="TRUE" ReadOnly="TRUE" Name="IssueID" Type="Computed" DisplayName="Issue ID" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="IssueID" FromBaseType="TRUE">
  <FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef Name="ID" />
  </FieldRefs>
  <DisplayPattern>
    <Column Name="ID" />
  </DisplayPattern>
</Field>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Field ID="{03f89857-27c9-4b58-aaab-620647deda9b}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" Name="LinkIssueIDNoMenu" DisplayName="Issue ID" Dir="" DisplayNameSrcField="IssueID" AuthoringInfo="(linked to item)" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="LinkIssueIDNoMenu">
  <FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef Name="ID" />
  </FieldRefs>
  <DisplayPattern>
    <HTML><![CDATA[<a  href="]]></HTML>
    <URL />
    <HTML><![CDATA[" ONCLICK="GoToLink(this);return false;" target="_self">]]></HTML>
    <Column HTMLEncode="TRUE" Name="ID" />
    <HTML><![CDATA[</a>]]></HTML>
  </DisplayPattern>
</Field>
```

Change the GUIDs and you can add these columns to a custom list, they will display in the manner you require. I would recommend creating a feature for the columns (maybe use [STSDev](http://www.codeplex.com/stsdev)) and releasing via a solution to any thing other than a dev site.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharePoint Designer to convert your list view into a Data View WebPart.   From there you have complete control over the XSL used for the view rendering which would make it trivial for you to link to the item from any or all fields.

Answer (score 0):

There is a powershell script available which you can use to add context menu for a field.

[ADD THE SHAREPOINT LIST ITEM'S CONTEXT MENU TO ANY COLUMN WITH POWERSHELL](http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2008/08/add-sharepoint-list-item-context-menu.html)

```
PS> & .\AddMenuColumn.ps1 -webUrl http://[server:port]/site/subsite/ -listName "Test" -fieldTitle "justAnyColumn" -addToDefaultView $true
```